# How to pronounce Eulerian when giving a talk?

Tags: terminology

When one gives a computational methods talk, what's the right way to pronounce "Eulerian"?

Is it like

1. oiler-ree-in, 5 syllables, or
2. oh-lure-ree-in, 4 syllables?

Langrangian is simple:

Langrange-Ian

I live in the United States, will attend an American PhD program, and English is my first language.

For Guassian, I have heard it pronounced:

Guass-see-in

or

Guass-shin (like "Russian"), which I prefer to use.

Comment: https://translate.google.it/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=it&text=eulerian

Comment: I think the first is closer to german, the second feels more french. Now try also russian (St. Peterburg) to have covered all stations of Eulers life.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the computational sciences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, the pronunciation of Eulerian is actually "You-leh-rian". But it's also ok (and understandable to everyone who is educated enough to understand the word) to say "Oy-leh-rian" (which is closer to the German original -- or at least about as close as American speakers typically get to a German-origin word).

"Guassian" is actually spelled "Gaussian" and is typically pronounced "Gaoo-ss-ian", with "ss" instead of "sh".

Comment: People actually say it as You-lerian?

Comment: @EMP: Yep, they do. It's in line with words such as eunuch, eustasy, euthanize, etc.

Comment: I've definitely heard the German pronunciation of Eulerian most of the time in the US- I don't know where Wolfgang has encountered the other pronunciation.  On Gaussian, I've encountered about a 50-50 split of ss vs. sh in the US.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I must have heard You-leh-rian often enough that it doesn't strike me as wrong any more -- even though I'm German by origin :-)